# Как собрать все objectName в ui_widgetname.h?

Tags: c++, qt5, c++11

Вопрос по Qt/ Создал много виджетов которые загружаются на одной главной форме.
Мне нужно собрать все ключи чтобы менять объектам текст(лэйбл). Есть конфиг прописанный с ключами и значениями которые загружаются в мапу    , где ключ это имя объекта а значение его текст. Как можно пройтись по всем разным файлам ui_wdgt.h чтобы поменять этот текст?

Comment: Либо руками меняйте, либо напишите программу

Comment: извиняюсь не уточнил. Это нужно для смены языка. то-есть при смене будет переписываться текст в зависимости от выбранного языка.

Comment: зачем вам придумывать костыли, если i18n уже есть в Qt: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/i18n-source-translation.html ?

Comment: Я знаю про него. тут проект создается в графическом, в консольном, для телефонов. И локализация должна быть одна. я бы уже давно сделал таким методом который вы предлагаете.

Comment: "проект создается в графическом, в консольном, для телефонов" - что это значит и чем это мешает сделать перевод штатным способом?

Comment: я бы с радостью так написал бы. Но есть ТЗ. пришлось писать монстра мапу в мапе. где первая мапа принимает ключ языка, вторая ключ-ключ кнопки например, а значение перевод.

Comment: в ТЗ сказано Запрещено использовать i18n :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то как-то так

```
QList <QLabel *> labels = findChildren<QLabel *>();
for(const auto label: labels)
    label->setText(translations.getText(label->objectName()));
```